# Non trivial examples of Sharepoint Hosted Apps

Tags: javascript, csom, sharepoint-hosted-app

A very simple question: there are tons of trivial examples of SP2013 hosted apps online showing how you can get simple things running with just a little bit of JavaScript.

One of the most elaborate examples is by [Jeremy Thake](http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/10/sharepoint-hosted-app-with-angularjs-for-mvc-javascript/) but even then, this is just a simple todo list and not a "real world" application.

I am looking for examples of apps that get a real job done. Bonus points if they use their own custom lists and cover all of the functionality available in SP hosted apps.

Answer (score 1):

This is an awesome example of using sharepoint hosted apps for reasonably complex implementations - [Learning Path Manager](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Learning-Path-Manager-Code-Sample) by Andrew Connel

It uses AngularJS + BreezeJS + `SP.UI.JS` to develop an add-in with the sharepoint look and feel.

You can checkout a  tutorial series around the same at [PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-sharepoint-apps-spa-angularjs)

Andrew Connel has a generic implementation demo around BreezeJs, AngularJS and SPHosted App [here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/Training/building-sharepoint-apps-as-single-page-apps-with-angularjs)

Further details on - [Andrew Connel's Blog](http://www.andrewconnell.com/Training/building-sharepoint-apps-as-single-page-apps-with-angularjs)

You need to have a good hands on around sharepoint rest API and AngularJS to completely be able to follow this tutorial

Comment: The first link in your answer seems to be different from the description. It is still useful so I would keep it but it seems the correct one should be: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Learning-Path-Manager-Code-Sample

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up references. The first link has, amongst others, the implementations for sharepoint Rest. If you go to the *Samples in this Repo* section and go to BreezeSP2013Sample, you will come to a implementation using SPHosted  app, angularjs and breezejs. I will update my answer.